# Windows Clustering Issue

Tags: windows, cluster, failover

We are setting up a SQL Server Cluster using the Windows Server 2008 R2 Failover Cluster.  We created a cluster and added the first node to it.  We then created a second server, but I believe that my system admins did a copy of the server instead of a new install.  Now the server, although having a new name, still thinks its already part of a failover cluster.  We then decided to start over from scratch with the failover cluster and distroyed the cluster.  The second server still believes its part of a current failover cluster and we see no way of removing that.  My guess is that there are some registry settings or something that didn't get reset.  Any one know how to clear this so that we can add the server to a new failover cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Command Line:

c:> Cluster node  /forcecleanup

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to run sysprep if you're going to copy an image of a node or else you'll end up with problems. Clusters are easily messed up by sloppy administrators.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the rep on serverfault to respond to the comment on the previous poster's command line suggestion.
1) Thanks for pointing out the Cluster command line option, I was buried in the UI so this is good to remember.
2) There is no /forcecleanup option.  Perhaps in some older version but not in the 2008 R2 instance that the OP is asking about.

Additionally I do not see how to perform any cleanup action from the command line.